# Averaging histograms with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I'm struggling with a statistic issues in Python. Please let me know if this should be transferred to Cross Validated.

I'm trying to produce a number of histograms, and then average them. Now I feel there is something fundamentally wrong with this. The following code does produce average distributions:

```
import numpy.linalg
from igraph import *
import random
import numpy as np

freqs = []
bins = []

for iter in range(100):
    G = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(100, .12, directed=False, loops=False)    
    L = G.laplacian(normalized=True)
    e = numpy.linalg.eigvals(L)
    freqs.append(numpy.histogram(e, bins=50)[0])
    bins.append(numpy.histogram(e, bins=50)[1])

meanFreq = np.mean(freqs,axis = 0)
meanBins = np.mean(bins,axis = 0)

print meanFreq
print meanBins
```

But... is this the right way to average histograms in Python/numpy? If not, is there any better way to do this, maybe with predefined numpy functions?

Thanks!

---

Here is a version including the suggestion of setting the bins beforehand, would this be statistically acceptable?

```
import numpy.linalg
from igraph import *
import random
import numpy as np

freq = []
b = []

bin = []

for i in range(0,200,2):
    b.append(float(i)/100)

for iter in range(100):
    G = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(100, .12, directed=False, loops=False)    
    L = G.laplacian(normalized=True)
    e = numpy.linalg.eigvals(L)
    freq.append(numpy.histogram(e, bins=b)[0])
    bin.append(numpy.histogram(e, bins=b)[1])

meanFreq = np.mean(freq,axis = 0)
meanBins = np.mean(bin,axis = 0)

print meanFreq
print meanBins
```

Comment: Much better to keep data in NumPy arrays rather than converting back and forward to Python lists

Comment: Note about `bins=50`: you may not have the same bin boundaries in every case, may be better to explicitly give the binning scheme. Also, you can always aggregate all the data and do the histogram only afterwards, in one go.

Comment: Seriously what @mdurant said: averaging `N` histograms of `N` different datasets is essentially finding a single histogram of all `N` datasets concatenated together (up to a factor of `N` for `meanFreq`; `meanBins` will be the same). So just store the eigenvalues in a single array and histogram them at the end. Also, don't generate the histogram twice just to get the two outputs! `f, b = numpy.histogram(e, bins=b); freq.append(f); bin.append(f);`

Comment: If you insist on computing 100 histograms and then averaging them, I would add a check in the loop to make sure all eigenvalues are strictly inside the `(b[0], b[-1])` interval, because if you have some huge eigenvalues, the right-most bin is going to get unnaturally saturated and skew your final averaged histogram; in that case, the program should quit and restart with more bins. (And did you mean to initialize `b = []` not `bin = []`? That loop should be vectorized: `b = numpy.arange(0, 200, 2)/100`.)

Comment: This is fantastic Ahmed. I tried and it works. Although, the frequency are now really high. Is there a way to normalize the histogram so that the total eigenvalue frequency is 1?

Here's my corrected code, by the way: https://gist.github.com/b67f6c67c8f5bcacf4ce.git

Do you mind converting your comment into an answer?

Thanks once again!